# .NET TPL CancellationToken memory leak

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-leaks, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I've developed a library which implements a producer/consumer pattern for work items. Work is dequeued and a separate task with continuations for failure and success is spun up for each dequeued work item.

The task continuations re-queue the work item after it completed (or failed) its work.

The entire library shares one central `CancellationTokenSource`, which is triggered on application shutdown.

I now face a major memory leak. If the tasks are created with the cancellation token as a parameter, then the tasks seem to remain in memory until the cancellation source is triggered (and later disposed).

This can be reproduced in this sample code (VB.NET). The main task is the task which would wrap the work item and the continuation tasks would handle the rescheduling.

```
Dim oCancellationTokenSource As New CancellationTokenSource
Dim oToken As CancellationToken = oCancellationTokenSource.Token
Dim nActiveTasks As Integer = 0

Dim lBaseMemory As Long = GC.GetTotalMemory(True)

For iteration = 0 To 100 ' do this 101 times to see how much the memory increases

  Dim lMemory As Long = GC.GetTotalMemory(True)

  Console.WriteLine("Memory at iteration start: " & lMemory.ToString("N0"))
  Console.WriteLine("  to baseline: " & (lMemory - lBaseMemory).ToString("N0"))

  For i As Integer = 0 To 1000 ' 1001 iterations to get an immediate, measurable impact
    Interlocked.Increment(nActiveTasks)
    Dim outer As Integer = i
    Dim oMainTask As New Task(Sub()
                                ' perform some work
                                Interlocked.Decrement(nActiveTasks)
                              End Sub, oToken)
    Dim inner As Integer = 1
    Dim oFaulted As Task = oMainTask.ContinueWith(Sub()
                                                    Console.WriteLine("Failed " & outer & "." & inner)
                                                    ' if failed, do something with the work and re-queue it, if possible
                                                    ' (imagine code for re-queueing - essentially just a synchronized list.add)

                                                                                                            ' Does not help:
                                                    ' oMainTask.Dispose()
                                                  End Sub, oToken, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default)
    ' if not using token, does not cause increase in memory:
    'End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)

            ' Does not help:
    ' oFaulted.ContinueWith(Sub()
    '                         oFaulted.Dispose()
    '                       End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)


    Dim oSucceeded As Task = oMainTask.ContinueWith(Sub()
                                                      ' success
                                                      ' re-queue for next iteration
                                                      ' (imagine code for re-queueing - essentially just a synchronized list.add)

                                                                                                                ' Does not help:
                                                      ' oMainTask.Dispose()
                                                    End Sub, oToken, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default)
    ' if not using token, does not cause increase in memory:
    'End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)

            ' Does not help:
    ' oSucceeded.ContinueWith(Sub()
    '                           oSucceeded.Dispose()
    '                         End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)


    ' This does not help either and makes processing much slower due to the thrown exception (at least one of these tasks is cancelled)
    'Dim oDisposeTask As New Task(Sub()
    '                               Try
    '                                 Task.WaitAll({oMainTask, oFaulted, oSucceeded, oFaultedFaulted, oSuccededFaulted})
    '                               Catch ex As Exception

    '                               End Try
    '                               oMainTask.Dispose()
    '                               oFaulted.Dispose()
    '                               oSucceeded.Dispose()                                     
    '                             End Sub)

    oMainTask.Start()
    '  oDisposeTask.Start()
  Next

  Console.WriteLine("Memory after creating tasks: " & GC.GetTotalMemory(True).ToString("N0"))

  ' Wait until all main tasks are finished (may not mean that continuations finished)

  Dim previousActive As Integer = nActiveTasks
  While nActiveTasks > 0
    If previousActive <> nActiveTasks Then
      Console.WriteLine("Active: " & nActiveTasks)
      Thread.Sleep(500)
      previousActive = nActiveTasks
    End If

  End While

  Console.WriteLine("Memory after tasks finished: " & GC.GetTotalMemory(True).ToString("N0"))

Next
```

I measured the memory use with the ANTS Memory Profiler and saw a large increase in the System.Threading.ExecutionContext, which traces back to task continuations and `CancellationCallbackInfo`.

As you can see, I already tried to dispose the tasks which use the cancellation token, but this seems to have no effect.

**Edit**

I'm using .NET 4.0

**Update**

Even when just chaining the main task with a continuation on failure, the memory use continuously rises. The task continuation seems to prevent the de-registration from the cancellation token registration.

So if a task is chained with a continuation, which does not run (due to the `TaskContinuationOptions`), then there seems to be a memory leak. If there is only one continuation, which runs, then I did not observe a memory leak.

**Workaround**

As a workaround, I can do a single continuation without any `TaskContinuationOptions` and handle the state of the parent task there:

```
oMainTask.ContinueWith(Sub(t)
                     If t.IsCanceled Then
                       ' ignore
                     ElseIf t.IsCompleted Then
                       ' reschedule

                     ElseIf t.IsFaulted Then
                       ' error handling

                     End If
                   End Sub)
```

I'll have to check how this performs in case of a cancellation but this seems to do the trick. I almost suspect a bug in the .NET Framework. Task cancellations with mutual exclusive conditions aren't something which could be this rare.

Comment: Can you give it a try without the Interlocked?

Comment: The Interlocked only exists for synchronization in this example - I want to wait for all tasks to have started before measuring memory. Removing it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Where are you waiting for them?

Comment: @i3arnon I'm not waiting anywhere. These tasks perform background work which does not yield a processable result (e.g.: work on database or files, transformation of data etc.)

Comment: Then I'll go back. What do you need the interlocked for?

Comment: @i3arnon Just in this example to make sure that all tasks have started before measuring memory. Due to the scheduling of worker threads in TPL a task may not be executed immediately. If I introduce a delay in the main task, it becomes more apparent that only a few threads are actually processing the tasks.

Comment: I understand. I'm just trying to filter out unneeded areas to see where your test goes wrong because this issue definitely doesn't reproduce (at least not on .Net 4.5)

Comment: @i3arnon There are some internal changes in 4.5 to how and when tasks create handles etc. Maybe that influences it. I don't have 4.5 available on this machine so I can't test it if this issue happens in .Net 4.5 - but switching to 4.5 would not be possible anyway (legacy stuff etc.)

Answer (score 5):

**Some observations**

1. The potential leak only seems present in the case where there is a task "branch" that does not run.  In your example, if you comment out the `oFaulted` task, the leak goes away for me.  If you update your code to have the `oMainTask` fault, so that the `oFaulted` task runs and the `oSucceeded` task does not run, then commenting out `oSucceeded` prevents the leak.
2. Perhaps not helpful, but if you call `oCancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` after all the tasks have run, the memory frees.  Dispose does not help, nor any combination of Disposing the cancellation source along with the tasks.
3. I took a look at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ which is 4.5.2 (Is there a way to view early frameworks?)  I know its not necessarily the same but its useful to know what types of things are going on.  Basically when you pass a cancellation token to a task, the task registers itself with the cancellation token's cancellation source.  So the cancellation source is holding references to all your tasks.  I'm not clear yet on why your scenario appears to be leaking.  I'll update after I've had a chance to look more in depth, if I find anything.

**Workaround**

Move your branching logic to a continuation that always runs.

```
Dim continuation As Task =
    oMainTask.ContinueWith(
        Sub(antecendent)
            If antecendent.Status = TaskStatus.Faulted Then
                'Handle errors
            ElseIf antecendent.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion Then
                'Do something else
            End If
        End Sub,
        oToken,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.Default)
```

There's a good chance this is lighter thant the other approach anyways.  In both cases one continuation always runs, but with this code only 1 continuation task gets created instead of 2.

Comment: Ack, right after reviewing my post, I noticed you updated with the same workaround I did.  I think I read this a couple days ago and didn't get a chance to post =T.  If I don't find anything else useful I guess I'll delete if this isn't adding anything new.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue under .net 4.0 by moving these 2 lines

```
Dim oCancellationTokenSource As New CancellationTokenSource
Dim oToken As CancellationToken = oCancellationTokenSource.Token
```

inside the first loop

then at the end of that loop

```
oToken = Nothing
oCancellationTokenSource.Dispose()
```

also I have moved the

```
Interlocked.Decrement(nActiveTasks)
```

inside each "final" task since the

```
While nActiveTasks > 0
```

would not be accurate.

here the code that work

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim nActiveTasks As Integer = 0

    Dim lBaseMemory As Long = GC.GetTotalMemory(True)

    For iteration = 0 To 100 ' do this 101 times to see how much the memory increases
        Dim oCancellationTokenSource As New CancellationTokenSource
        Dim oToken As CancellationToken = oCancellationTokenSource.Token
        Dim lMemory As Long = GC.GetTotalMemory(True)

        Console.WriteLine("Memory at iteration start: " & lMemory.ToString("N0"))
        Console.WriteLine("  to baseline: " & (lMemory - lBaseMemory).ToString("N0"))

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000 ' 1001 iterations to get an immediate, measurable impact
            Dim outer As Integer = iteration
            Dim inner As Integer = i

            Interlocked.Increment(nActiveTasks)

            Dim oMainTask As New Task(Sub()
                                          ' perform some work
                                      End Sub, oToken, TaskCreationOptions.None)

            oMainTask.ContinueWith(Sub()
                                       Console.WriteLine("Failed " & outer & "." & inner)
                                       Interlocked.Decrement(nActiveTasks)
                                   End Sub, oToken, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default)


            oMainTask.ContinueWith(Sub()
                                       If inner Mod 250 = 0 Then Console.WriteLine("Success " & outer & "." & inner)
                                       Interlocked.Decrement(nActiveTasks)
                                   End Sub, oToken, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default)


            oMainTask.Start()
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("Memory after creating tasks: " & GC.GetTotalMemory(True).ToString("N0"))


        Dim previousActive As Integer = nActiveTasks
        While nActiveTasks > 0
            If previousActive <> nActiveTasks Then
                Console.WriteLine("Active: " & nActiveTasks)
                Thread.Sleep(500)
                previousActive = nActiveTasks
            End If

        End While

        oToken = Nothing
        oCancellationTokenSource.Dispose()

        Console.WriteLine("Memory after tasks finished: " & GC.GetTotalMemory(True).ToString("N0"))

    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Final Memory after finished: " & GC.GetTotalMemory(True).ToString("N0"))

    Console.Read()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: That would cancel the cancellation source in each iteration. Of course you don't get any memory leaks then. If I cancel after all iterations it cleans up fine too. Kind of beats the purpose of having a central cancellation source :)